# Angular ngAnimate included but not adding classes

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a simple codepen setup to demonstrate my problem. I have also looked through all similar threads but have been unable to resolve this problem still.

This is the HTML5 + Angular markup:

```
 <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-if="test === true">Hello!</div>
  <button ng-click="test = !test">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

This is the Angular controller:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('testController', function($scope){
  $scope.test = true;
});
```

This is the CSS:

```
.ng-enter{
  left: -100%;
}

.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
  left: 0%;
}

.ng-leave{
  left: 0%;
}

.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
  left: 100%;
}
```

Here is the link to the interactive pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvoGjg

Am I missing something? My versions are the same, module is included in the init function... ARG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, you just aren't seeing anything happen because you have two issues:

- You haven't included any transition declarations in your CSS style, so they happen immediately, so it's not very animated.

  So add a CSS transition like this for each `.ng-` state:

  ```
  transition:3s linear all;
  ```
- You haven't set the `position: absolute` on the target `<div>`, so the `left` style doesn't do anything on a relatively positioned element.

  ```
  <div ng-if="test === true" style="position: absolute">Hello!</div>
  ```

[Updated codepen example.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdBwaj)